# How to have a function expose its objects and member methods using RequireJS AMD

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Can someone explain to me the process involved to have a function expose its objects and member methods to another defined object using RequireJS AMD?
For example, I have the following defined in hello.js

```
define(['jquery','student'], function($,stu){
    var sayHello = function(){
        var post = $('#post').html();
        post.html('Hello, student!');
        post.html(post+stu.name.full());
    };
});

define('student',function(){
    var st = function(){};
    st.name = {
        first: 'Johnny',
        middle: 'Jay',
        last: 'Dabby',
        full: function(){
            return (st.name.first + ' '+ st.name.middle + ' '+st.name.last);
        }
    };
    st.course = {
        math: 'Algebra II',
        science: 'Chemistry',
        social_sci: 'World History',
        foreign_lang: 'French',
        getCourse: function(){
             return st.course.math;
        }
    };
    st.activity = {
        study: '1.5 hrs',
        homework: '0.55 hrs',
        break: '1.0 hr',
        extraCurricula: '0.50 hrs',
        getActivity: function(){
            return st.activity.homework;
        }
    };
    return st;
});
```

I'm trying to integrate this example or something similar to it into a large application, however, the debugger kept throwing "TypeError", saying stu.name.full is not a function. Can some explain what I need to do correct the coding style?

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide, either make `st` a class and create an instance from it, or just make `st` a namespace `Object` and use it.

The easiest fix is to replace `var st = function(){}` with `var st = {}`.

```
define('student',function(){
    var st = {};
    st.name = {
        first: 'Johnny',
        middle: 'Jay',
        last: 'Dabby',
        full: function(){
            return (st.name.first + ' '+ st.name.middle + ' '+st.name.last);
        }
    };
    st.course = {
        math: 'Algebra II',
        science: 'Chemistry',
        social_sci: 'World History',
        foreign_lang: 'French',
        getCourse: function(){
             return st.course.math;
        }
    };
    st.activity = {
        study: '1.5 hrs',
        homework: '0.55 hrs',
        break: '1.0 hr',
        extraCurricula: '0.50 hrs',
        getActivity: function(){
            return st.activity.homework;
        }
    };
    return st;
});
```

Comment: Cristy, thank you. The bug issue is resolved. Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

1. In hello.js, you are not returning any thing from the module. The whole purpose of the module is to reuse the module in other part of the application. So, i would suggest to return the Object which defines the Module. Something like..

**Hello.js**

```
define(['jquery','student'], function($,stu){
        var sayHello = function(){
            var post = $('#post').html();
            post.html('Hello, student!');
            post.html(post+stu.name.full());
        };
      return { 
             publicHello : sayHello
         };
    });
```

2. In your `Student` Module, you are defining the properties on the `student` `function` and not on the `student` Object. So, you need to first define an empty object with statement like  `var st = {};` and then add properties which you want to expose from this module. At the end, you return the `st` Object literal which is what this module returns. Additionally, note that `name` is an internal property in the `function` and return the functions name.

**Student.js**

```
define('student',function(){
    var st = {};
    st.name = {
        first: 'Johnny',
        middle: 'Jay',
        last: 'Dabby',
        full: function(){
            return (st.name.first + ' '+ st.name.middle + ' '+st.name.last);
        }
    };
    st.course = {
        math: 'Algebra II',
        science: 'Chemistry',
        social_sci: 'World History',
        foreign_lang: 'French',
        getCourse: function(){
             return st.course.math;
        }
    };
    st.activity = {
        study: '1.5 hrs',
        homework: '0.55 hrs',
        break: '1.0 hr',
        extraCurricula: '0.50 hrs',
        getActivity: function(){
            return st.activity.homework;
        }
    };
    return st;
    });
```

**Why are you getting the error "TypeError", saying stu.name.full is not a function ?**

When you JS engine runs the code statement `var st = function(){};` it creates a `st` function. Every `functions` gets certain predefined properties from function prototype like `name`, `length`, `arguments`.

When you try to create the name property like as shown below, it is trying to override the `name` property of the function with a new Object literal. However, the function `name` property is not writable, hence it can't be changed. So, basically, the below code is effectively not doing anything and still the `st.name` will have the value of `st`, even after executing the below statement.

Now, when you use the student module in the Hello.js, the exported module points to a function `st` and the `st.name` has a value `st`. Using the code like `stu.name.full()` is actually calling the function which doesn't exists and there is no property named full on the `name`. Hence you get the `Type error`.

```
st.name = {
        first: 'Johnny',
        middle: 'Jay',
        last: 'Dabby',
        full: function(){
            return (st.name.first + ' '+ st.name.middle + ' '+st.name.last);
        }
    };
```

It is suggested to use the strict mode using "use strict" to allow JS engine to throw an error when any invalid operation is specified.

```js
"use strict";

var st = function(){};
st.name = {};
```

Comment: Agalo, thank you. The bug issue is resolved. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Didum - Glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote, mark  as answer if it helped you.